# Coverting java request to c#

Tags: java, c#, xamarin.android, dotnet-httpclient

I am trying to convert this request written java  to c#(Xamarin android) , java one seems to be working , but c# one is failing with bad request(400) .
Could you please point out if i am translating rightly ?

Java code

```
String url = "https://someUrl";

try {
    URL url1 = new URL(url);
    URLConnection uc = url1.openConnection();

    String basicAuth = Base64.encodeToString((APIKEY).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.NO_WRAP);

    uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", basicAuth);
    InputStream in = uc.getInputStream();

    // Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

C# code

```
String url = "https://someUrl";
// Add custom implementation here as needed.
var uri = new Uri(url);

var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (API_KEY), Base64FormattingOptions.None);

try
{
    using(var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.Debug ("TokenSending", "failed to send token" + e);
}
```

Comment: Could you post the requests here? Or at least the auth headers

Comment: all i have is that java code ,i have posted above and that is working ! , i can send u the response body if that can help !,
you could just confirm me if i have written exactly same thing?

Comment: Try at least to log the values of basicAuth and authHeaderValue variables so you can compare them just to check the problem is not there. The ideal would be to log the full request to do a full comparison.

Comment: Thnx you ! after that will let u know

Comment: Please install Fiddler and trace the transfer to show his exactly what gets transferred.